# in TLS/SSL, what's the purpose of staging from premaster secret to master secret and then to encryption keys?

Tags: ssl, encryption

Why don't client and server just exchange the encryption keys directly using public key encryption or DH key exchange protocol? What the rationale behind that or what the problem it is to solve?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Try asking this on http://crypto.stackexchange.com or http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its helpful to understand how keys are derived in modern SSL/TLS. Things were  a bit different in early SSL (like SSLv2).

The `master_secret` is a common secret shared by the client and server. It is used to derive session specific keys. The `master_secret` derived form other parameters (discussed below).

There are 6 each secrets derived from the `master_secret`:

- Client encryption key
- Server encryption key
- Client MAC key
- Server MAC key
- Client IV
- Server IV

Assuming that *neither* `eNULL` nor `aNULL` is used, both the client and server use an encryption key for confidentiality and a HMAC key for authenticity. Each (client and server) has its own key.

While IVs are usually considered public, SSL/TLS treats them as secret parameters.

From [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246), the `master_secret` is derived as:

```
master_secret = PRF(pre_master_secret, "master secret",
                    ClientHello.random + ServerHello.random)
                    [0..47];
```

The `pre_master_secret` comes from key agreement or key transport. If it comes from key agreement, then the `pre_master_secret` is the result of Diffie-Hellman key agreement. In an agreement scheme, both parties contribute to the derived secret.

If the `pre_master_secret` comes from a key transport scheme, then the client encrypts a random value under the server's public key. In this scheme, only the client provides keying material. When only one party provides the key, its called a key transport scheme.

---

> What the rationale behind that or what the problem it is to solve?

The first stage, where the `pre_master_secret` is used, provides a "pluggable" architecture for key agreement or key transport.

The second stage, where the `master_secret` is derived, ensures both the client and server contribute to the keying material.

In addition, there's a label - "master secret" - that helps ensure derivation is unique even if the same parameters are used for something else (assuming a different derivation uses a different label). Use of labels are discussed in SP800-56 and SP800-57 (among other places).

The hash used in the second stage, where the `master_secret` is derived, performs two functions. First, it performs a mixing function. Second, it maps elements in the group used by key exchange or key agreement into random bit patterns.

The final stage is the derivation of the 6 keys from `master_secret`. According to 6.3. Key Calculation, the derivation *does not* provide key independence. It just ensures interoperability:

```
   To generate the key material, compute

      key_block = PRF(SecurityParameters.master_secret,
                      "key expansion",
                      SecurityParameters.server_random +
                      SecurityParameters.client_random);

   until enough output has been generated.  Then, the key_block is
   partitioned as follows:

      client_write_MAC_key[SecurityParameters.mac_key_length]
      server_write_MAC_key[SecurityParameters.mac_key_length]
      client_write_key[SecurityParameters.enc_key_length]
      server_write_key[SecurityParameters.enc_key_length]
      client_write_IV[SecurityParameters.fixed_iv_length]
      server_write_IV[SecurityParameters.fixed_iv_length]
```

The steps above are a solid design. However, when used in SSL/TLS, there are lots of devils running around. For example, the above is *not* enough when a feature like renegotiation is added (triple handshake attack ftw!).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason is that if the client simply selected a random number to use as the symmetric key and encrypted it using the server's public key to send to the server, there would potentially be a vulnerability if common clients used an imperfect random number generator, leading to predictable symmetric keys and making the communications much easier to break.

The actual key exchange protocol ensures that the symmetric key contains randomized elements from both the client and the server.  This means that even if the client has an imperfect random number generator, the communications are still protected if the server's random number generator is cryptographically strong.  Even if both the client's and the server's random number generators have weaknesses, the attack against the combination of the two is likely to be more expensive than if only the client's random number generator were used.

Answer (score 0):

The rationale is that if the secret key is never exchanged it can never be detected. Key negotation algiorithms are known to be secure. An encryption is only as secure as its key.

Answer (score 0):

pre master key to master key: 
    one side random is not really random, but 2 side 3 times random number could be really random..

master key to 6 key pairs: 
    2 for encryption, 2 for message integration check, and 2 for preventing CBC attack